# Restore default Finder keyboard shortcut for Sort by Name

Tags: keyboard, finder

The default keyboard shortcut to sort by Name is <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd> as described [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/finder-keyboard-shortcuts-cheat-sheet-mac/). However in  my Finder menu, **Name** does not have a keyboard shortcut.

I have gone through all my App Shortcuts and nothing else is mapped to <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd>. I have tried adding the shortcut manually with the exact string "Name", but it does not get added to Sort By -> Name; it gets added to Group By -> Name.

How do I restore the default shortcut for Sort By -> Name?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably find that key command has been assigned to another menu item in Finder. That will definitely 'steal' it from the default.

Here I've intentionally used that command for 'Use Stacks', which you can see has removed the one for 'Name'.

[image]

If you go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts >App Shortcuts you will likely find the culprit.  You can either delete this with the  <kbd>-</kbd>  button underneath, or change the shortcut to something that doesn't conflict.

[image]

I'm aware the locations of prefs have changed with Ventura, but I don't yet have a Mac with Ventura to test this new location. I'm sure you should be able to find it - or someone might kindly add this information.

*After comments*
As it appears to not have been 'stolen' in this manner, then one way to force it back is to add it again in Prefs. Because this particular menu item appears twice in different sub-menus, you can force a specific instance by quoting its 'full path' in the prefs, e.g. `View->Sort By->Name`

Comment: Unfortunately I checked all my other App Shortcuts, and there is no conflicting shortcut. Thanks though, I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: You can force a specific item in case of duplicate names by using its 'full path' e.g `View->Sort By->Date Created`- https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAVoP.png - I still can't figure how else you would steal it. You cannot remove a menu shortcut, only replace one.

Comment: That works!!! Thank you so much. If you add that to your answer I will accept it.

Comment: Another "interesting" quirk: For a Sort By item keyboard shortcut item to work, "Use Groups" has to be unchecked. This is because the Group By list replaces the Sort by list when it is checked. In this case, you have to enter a shortcut to toggle "Use Groups" off, and *then* the shortcut for the Sort By item. Luckily, it remembers the last used Sort By, so I just leave it sorted by Name and assign the shortcut I wanted for Sort By -> Name to "Use Groups" itself.

Comment: Yes, you can't use any type of 'wildcard' structure for key commands. They're not that smart. Any menu item that changes depending on context can't be easily re-keyed.

Comment: Note that Group By shortcuts work even if "Use Groups" is toggled off. It will get toggle on as soon as the shortcut is activated. The reverse is not true for Sort By shortcuts.

Comment: hmm… OK. I'm out of my comfort zone now - I never use groups & only ever sort by name or date, for which I click the column at the top of the window ;))

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is a "quirk" with this particular menu item. Sort by -> Name has the same exact item text as Group By -> Name, and Group By -> Name takes precedence. What this means it that when you set an App Shortcut for "Name", it will apply to Group By -> Name, and it will *remove* the default shortcut for Sort By -> Name.

Remove "Name" from Finder App Shortcuts and the default will be restored.

Comment: So it *had* been stolen, as I first surmised?? The behaviour of added key commands is always seemingly 'random' if the item appears more than once in the menus, hence the syntax to force it.

Comment: It had been stolen, but not by the shortcut! By the Name ‍♀️

Comment: It would still appear to have been stolen by the addition of a user-added shortcut which just happened to reference the wrong item, mistakenly thought to be 'correct'. If not, then I'm lost ;))